# Assign double in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, geodjango

I am working on a Django website, and one of my models is defined like this:

```
class Field(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_ext)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bounds = models.PolygonField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Field'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def getAcres(self):
        self.bounds.transform(32118)
        acres = self.bounds.area * 0.000247105381
        return round(acres, 2)

    def getCenter(self):
        center = [self.bounds.centroid.x, self.bounds.centroid.y]
        return center
```

I have an index.html that contains an open layers map, whose center is initialized as such:

```
var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-88.455, 39.999]);
```

I want to change this so the 'center' variable will be initialized to the center of  the 'bounds' field of my Field model. I tried this:`var center = {{field.0.getCenter}}` but that did not work. Is it even possible to assign variables in such a manner?

Comment: What exactly gone wrong? Are you sure that `field` is a list of `Field` instances?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ field.getCenter }}
```

...but `getCenter` needs to return a string, like '0.112, 14.123'. Alternate:

```
var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([{{ field.bounds.centroid.x }}, {{ field.bounds.centroid.x }}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `field` is an instance of `Field` model, try:

```
var center = {{ field.getCenter }};
```